# Тестирование программно-апаратного комплекса на arduino+android - с чего начать?

Tags: android, arduino, android-testing

У меня есть программно-апаратный комплекс которые построен на микроконтроллере Arduino UNO-R3 и на приложении которое установлено на телефон. Управлять микроконтроллером можно с телефона посредством блютуз. Вопрос возник довольно непростой - как этот комплекс протестировать. Имеется в виду полноценное тестирование и документирование тестов. Я не прошу за меня сделать какую-то работу, потому что я хочу самостоятельно разобраться что и как делать. Но я не могу понять в какую сторону нужно двигаться. Не знаю нужно ли ооочень сильно углубляться в тестирование и потеряться в этих тестах. Надеюсь что есть инструменты для тестирования, чтобы можно было это все красиво представить в документации. Надеюсь на полезные советы.

P.S. Если не дал какой-то важной и нужной информации то постараюсь дополнить вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо создавать стенд проверки, который будет контролировать все реакции Вашего контроллера.

Составляете список команд, которые должны выполняться. Потом пишете программу, которая на телефоне последовательно выдает эти команды на контроллер. Одновременно контролируете реакцию контроллера с помощью стенда проверки. Стенд проверки скорее всего надо сделать тоже на ардуинке, только там, где в Вашем контроллере сигнал выдачи, в стенде проверки должен быть сигнал приема. А там, где в Вашем контроллере сигнал приема, в стенде проверки должен быть сигнал выдачи. Соединяете Ваш контроллер со стендом, а стенд с телефоном. Потом пишете на телефоне тестовую программу (тестовые программы в случае сложных алгоритмов). В этих программах последовательно выдаете на Ваш контроллер все команды, которые он должен отрабатывать. Контролируете реакцию Вашего контроллера с помощью стенда проверки. Работа большая, особенно если входов-выходов много.

UPD1:

> а можно как-то все это описать без создания стенда и написания
>   тестовой программы? глупый вопрос конечно, но времение не очень много
>   к сожалению :( – Andrew Goroshko 4 секунды назад

Если у Вас единичное изделие, то Вы можете вручную его оттестировать с помощью тестера, осциллографа, лопаты и какой-то мамы. Если у Вас серия хотя бы из 10 изделий, то уже имеет смысл делать стенд. Если у Вас серия из 100 изделий, то без стенда Вы эту работу просто не сделаете. Если у Вас серия из 1000 изделий, то Вам понадобится не один стенд и персонал для тестирования. Ну и так далее. Каждый следующий ноль в серийности означает коренную перестройке производства и соответствующие денежные затраты.

Одно изделие еще может сделать один радиолюбитель. Напрягшись, один радиолюбитель может сделать серию из 10 штук. Но серия из 100+ изделий уже требует фирмы, денег, кредитов, помещений, рабочих и далее со всеми остановками.

Comment: а можно как-то все это описать без создания стенда и написания тестовой программы? глупый вопрос конечно, но времение не очень много к сожалению :(